# Session and Login User data with Node and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, session

I need to know that if my authentication and session management method is right.

I am using session management as when I receive successful auth. from node server. I store user data(without any trace of pass.) in $window.sessionStorage and if user marked rememberMe(checkbox), store data in $window.localStorage too.

Through this I am able to get data in different controllers. Though I read somewhere about session implementation at server(nodeJs) side is also possible. But I am not sure about how to use session along with JSONToken Authentication.

I was using 
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/12/09/MEAN-Stack-User-Registration-and-Login-Example.aspx 
as a learning example but I could not understand it.

/app/app.js

Why is it in the run() method ?

```
    // add JWT token as default auth header
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + $window.jwtToken;
```

and what is this:

```
// manually bootstrap angular after the JWT token is retrieved from the server
$(function () {
    // get JWT token from server
    $.get('/app/token', function (token) {
        window.jwtToken = token;

        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    });
});
```

/controllers/app.controller.js

```
// use session auth to secure the angular app files
router.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.path !== '/login' && !req.session.token) {
        return res.redirect('/login?returnUrl=' + encodeURIComponent('/app' + req.path));
    }

    next();
});

// make JWT token available to angular app
router.get('/token', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.session.token);
});

// serve angular app files from the '/app' route
router.use('/', express.static('app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

So using a session server-side with JWT kind of defeats the purpose of using JWT.  JWT's are awesome in a number of ways, but one of the ways they are great, is regardless which server intercepts a request, they can verify the user.

If you put it in a session, you have to make sure the client keeps going to the same server as the session is saved in memory on that machine.  There are plenty of ways around that, but again it kind of defeats the purpose of a JSON web token.

What I did for my authentication with angular/node/JWT was just passed the JWT back in the header every time, and with my middleware intercepted it with:

```
req.header.whatever_my_tokens_name_is
```

Comment: What about storing data in sessionStorage and localStorage ?

Comment: Those are fine as those are on the client side.  So you just grab them from the client and pass them back to the server on each use.  I would however discourage using a session on your server-side.  Understand that using localStorage can open you up to XSS attacks, so make sure you use appropriate headers in your application.  Angular does have quite a bit of built in defense against it though!  I use localStorage for my application.  Something else you should do, is not have a difference of localStorage and sessionStorage, just expire/update JWT's as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The code below set the $http to send on every request the JWT Token to the server.

```
// add JWT token as default auth header
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + $window.jwtToken;
```

The code below get the token from '/app/token' and store it in LocalStorage. After that, it starts the angular.

```
// manually bootstrap angular after the JWT token is retrieved from the server
$(function () {
    // get JWT token from server
    $.get('/app/token', function (token) {
        window.jwtToken = token;

        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    });
});
```

Here this is a middleware that check if there are no token stored in req.session.token and requested url is not '/login'. If so, send a redirect to '/login'.

```
// use session auth to secure the angular app files
router.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.path !== '/login' && !req.session.token) {
        return res.redirect('/login?returnUrl=' + encodeURIComponent('/app' + req.path));
    }

    next();
});
```

Finally here, this is a endpoint to the client request the '/token' again from the server.

```
// make JWT token available to angular app
router.get('/token', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.session.token);
});
```

Anyway, check the @morgan-g response regarless session-side and JWT.

I hope this helps.